# How to power 2 15.2v 57.2 watts peltier plates

Tags: power-supply, power, peltier

I am building a custom peltier cooler out of aluminum insulated with styrofoam I currently have 2 tec-12706 peltier plates and 2 PC fans what would be a adequate power supply for this setup?

Comment: What are you trying to cool? Air? Walls? Container? Shouldn't you be concerned about *volume" rather than area? You need to look up the heat capacity of each of the elements and then work out the energy you are trying to remove. Remember that it will take more energy to bring the temperature down than to maintain it so you also need to specify a response time. I strongly recommend that you work in SI units.

Comment: More info needed. What is IN the space. Where does heat come from? Is it insulated ? What are you trying to do? 100W of Peltiers in unlikely to work well enough in most applications. Repurposing an old fridge or a dehumidifier is liable to be an easier method.

Comment: You'd need to know the R value of the room first and the average temperature outside the room

Comment: Trying to cool a grow tent that's 2x2x4 heat is coming off of a 450w led light tent is in closet with closet door open and tent open inside of an efficiency. I have a window ac unit at 68° at all times. I would like to be able to close my tent and keep the temp in the mid 70s to 80 max

Comment: Build an evaporative (aka swamp or bong) cooler. Its lowest temperature is governed by the dewpoint of the air outside, so won't necessarily always reach your required goal, but it's cheap to build, and cheap to run.

Comment: Since the light is generating all the heat, if you can have the heatsink of the light be outside the tent, blowing air across it will be pretty efficient (because of the big heat differential) and decrease your cooling needs for the actual tent part

Comment: Typical grow lights are either high-pressure sodium or LED. A remoted heat pipe or liquid cooling might work for LED, but would require a lot of custom work and expense. For HPS there’s no way to do that, other than circulating outside air across the bulb. Again, more expense. This stuff matters, especially when prices for the, ahem, product are going lower.

Comment: I was thinking about the tent sealing around the top of the light, and just blowing air across it outside.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, you explained that you are:

> Trying to cool a grow tent that's 2x2x4 heat is coming off of a 450w led

A 450W LED will put off roughly 450W of heat. Typical efficiency for a Peltier cooler is 10%, so you'd need something like 4.5 kW worth of Peltier elements (i.e, about 75-80 of the plates you're looking at). You'd also need to supply over 300A of power at 15V to those elements (which would involve a 30+ amp 120V circuit -- this is at least double what you can get from a typical house AC socket), and you'd need to dissipate that 4.5 kW at the hot end (which will require a substantial heat sink / fan configuration, easily another couple hundred watts worth of active cooling).

If it isn't already obvious: this is completely infeasible. Use a traditional air conditioner.

Answer (score 0):

I would look first to using a small split air conditioner for this kind of application. Second choice, a portable A/C unit. Peltier efficiency is very low so it doesn’t make much sense for a space this size.

Comment: Dnt have any small ac units that wont draw to much power

Comment: Looking for something energy efficient since light is a lil expensive where I'm at

Comment: Supposedly I need a 4500 but ac unit

Comment: Btu* would self evaporating ac unit work better?

Comment: For a grow room / tent you’re trying to manage humidity too to prevent mold, an evap unit would work against you there. The rooms I’ve seen are usually using split units or portables. The split unit has the advantage that it can be mounted high off the floor. Oh, and don’t forget about some kind of absorber to deal with the smell, and some fans to circulate the air.

Comment: The compressor unit, be it a portable or split type, will be much more efficient than the Peltier, by far.

Comment: If I could show u the setup I have it might be easier